# Any way to save the folder view for a mapped drive/folder inwindows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I searched for this and still have not found anything. I have a mapped drive in Windows 7 x64 that contains folders of photos. I am constantly changing the Folder View to `Large Icons`, but it changes back to `Details` (my default folder view) the next day. I tried to change the Mapped Drive Properties to Optimize for Pictures (and sub-folders) but it sill changes back the next day.

Is there any way to save a custom view for a mapped drive/folder in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

The settings for this are stored in the following registry locations:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

But I'm quite sure that mapped drives are purposefully excluded from this list.  You can try to delete the registry keys listed above and only recreate the last two, but that won't work.  If the mapped drive is linked to a windows machine, you could get there by shortcut and not by mapping and that would solve your issue.

Comment: They are mapped to Synology diskstation folders. Does that mean there's no way to save the view?

Comment: That's correct.  You could try to  manually add the information to the registry keys I listed, but I'm sure that won't work.